# Error in reading the name attribute value from an html file

Tags: java

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("mypage.html"));
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();  
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(int i=0 , size = nodeList.getLength() ; i < size ; i++){
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
    }
```

I am using the above code to get value inside name attribute in input tag from some html file.

To be more clear I am trying to print - firstname and last name from this simple html file code

```
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" />
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" />
```

But the error comes:
[Fatal Error] ... The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "/input> ...

Any change in code or suggestion is most welcomed.

Comment: What's unclear about the error? Your html has a tag <input> with no closing tag </input>.

Comment: How are you trying to parse this? With an XML parser? That doesn't look to be valid XML. Shouldn't use use an HTML parser like JSoup?

Comment: @nhouser9: but it does -- it's an isolated tag and  closes itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't say the tag wasn't closed. I said it does not have a </input> tag, which is quite true and also the source of the error.

Comment: It's also [bad and poorly supported XHMTL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778903/why-does-some-html-beginning-tags-end-with-a-forward-slash).

Comment: input doesn't have an end tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: I don't have any ideas about how to print the data. I read a little about JSoup and all. This is all I could gather.

Comment: And moreover is it possible for some code to read both html and xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what the error says,

> [Fatal Error] ... The element type "input" must be terminated by the
>   matching end-tag "/input> ...

I think it is expecting that the html is in this format. With the input tag having its respected closing tag `</input>`

```
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"></input>
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"></input>
```

Comment: But html input doesn't have an end tag. and i was hoping that the code could read both html and xml file but for now html is much more important

Comment: @PraveenRana In XML all tags MUST have a closing tag. Using a library for XML to parse HTML (where some tags do not have closing tags) is like making a square peg fit in a circular hole. You can write code to force it do what you want, or use a library that is design to parse html. I if i were you, i would be using jsoup https://jsoup.org/